# Change the selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list that I fill with some values like that :

```
<form>
    <select id="select_region" class="form-control" name="regions" onchange="loadPage(this.value);">
        <?php
            foreach ($regions as $region)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$region->nom.'">'.$region->nom.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

As you can see, there is a attribute `onchange` which call a javascript function. In this function, I redirect the page to have the selectionned item in the url.  Like that :

```
function loadPage(param){
  $string = "/kohana-v3.3.5/environment/region/"+param
  self.location.href= escape($string);
}
```

The problem is that when it reloads the page, the dropdown always shows the first item of the list.

So what I want is that when the user select an option, the page is redirected but the dropdown shows the value that he choose.

I tried with jquery by adding :

```
$("#select_region").val(param);
```

But as the page is realoaded, it's reset.

Can someone tell me how should I do it please ?

**EDIT :**
Functions with `localstorage` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value_selected = localStorage.getItem("Select");
    $("#select_region").val(value_selected);
});

function loadPage(param){

    store_value(param);


    $string = "/kohana-v3.3.5/environment/region/"+param
    self.location.href= escape($string);


}

function store_value(value){
    localStorage.setItem("value", value);
}
```

Comment: Are you putting this in `$("#select_region").val(param);` in document ready?

Comment: @MHassan I'm putting it inside the function `loadPage` because it uses the parameter `param`

Comment: What you have should work so long as the `param` value is a valid value of the select and the element exists at the point you execute your code.

Comment: check console.log( $string) what it reutrn

Comment: Try $("select#select_region option:selected").text(param)

Comment: You should put `$("#select_region").val(param);` in `'$(document).ready(function(){ //here });' in order to work. I am supposing  `param` has valid value selected on page load.

Comment: @rkatkam It doesn't work :/

Comment: @uzaif the string is ok, my page is reloaded, as I expect

Comment: @MHassan I can't, because I need to have the parameter of the function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The `param` is ok. Just to check, the function `.val()` does to the "value" attribute of the `<option>` ?

Comment: you want to option selected after reload page

Comment: @uzaif Yes, but I need the parameter

Comment: In order to keep previous value selected by user, you should have saved it when user select it. If you are not storing it, you can use localstorage for temprary data storage.

Comment: ya @MHassan  this way problem can be solve

Comment: @MHassan Thanks I will check it. I never tried this way

Comment: I have posted answer for using localstorage. You can explore it further.

Comment: you are storing value with key 'value' and getting it with 'Select'. Use same key for both purpose

Answer (score 0):

Either you pass a var with the url like `page.php?id=1254`,
or have a look at `localstorage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store value in localstorage like this

```
function store_value(value)    
   if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
       localStorage.setItem("value", value);
   } else {
       // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
   }
}
```

call this function in `loadPage` and pass it value of selected drop down value. For getting its value on page load,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value_selected = localStorage.getItem('value');
    $("#select_region").val(value_selected);
});
```

Comment: The same way as you. I will edit the post with my new code

Comment: you are storing value with key 'value' and getting it with 'Select'. Use same key for both purpose.

Comment: check in localstorage in your console that whether value is being stored or not.

Comment: With firebug, it says : **ReferenceError: $ is not defined $('#select_region').val(value_selected);**

Comment: Its mean you hav not loaded jquery. here is a working exmpla (https://jsbin.com/putemapuso/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Ok, I resolved the problem with jquery. But it doesn't work. And in your example, you don't refresh the page

Comment: Type localStorage in console and check whether you value is stored or not.